# What I have to do to install Proprietary drivers?

Tags: drivers, ati, radeon, fglrx, proprietary

I have Ubuntu 13.10, and I want to use it to play games on wine, like League of Legends and World of warcraft, so I'm trying to install proprietary drivers. I have an Ati Mobility Radeon HD 5470, so the question is if i have to only click here (the pick is not mine)

[image]

in fglrx-updates? or I have to download something?
Another question, is 3d acceleration enabled with this drivers?
Thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to install ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx)

Comment: Are the games you want to run not being able to run? Have you tested them before messing up with the system? Normally Ubuntu comes ready and you only need to install the drivers to fix problems; Have you had any problem with those games?

Comment: A months ago when I tried to install ubuntu 12.10, I had low fps in this games (with the open source drivers), and in Windows I have 50-60fps. So I think it was because I was playing wine and not native games, but I think that with the proprietary drivers I'll have a better performance (thats what I read)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is smart to update first.

Yes, select fglrx-updates and Apply changes, the rest should be done automagically.

Yes, 3D acceleration is enabled in the proprietary driver.

Comment: thanks for answering, I come from windows, is performance much reduced on gaming? also i will try to install the 3.12 kernel

Comment: best to stick with the defaults if you are new to ubuntu. If you run games which are ported to linux your games may even run faster than their windows counterparts. You are used to download programs from the internet, install and run them. Don't do this in Ubuntu...Everything is installed via the packetmanager. Also, install "synaptic"; this is more powerful than software center (but in software center you will in the beginning find it easier to find what you look for. Welcome to Ubuntu :-)